# Getting JSON object from within String Android

Tags: android, json

I am trying to get the information within the DATA array, but keep getting nothing. I am parsing this data from Dark Sky API:

```
hourly: {
summary: "Mostly cloudy later this morning.",
icon: "partly-cloudy-day",
data: [
{
time: 1364389200,
summary: "Partly Cloudy",
icon: "partly-cloudy-night",
precipIntensity: 0,
temperature: 29.8,
windSpeed: 2.44,
windBearing: 60,
cloudCover: 0.41,
humidity: 0.88,
pressure: 831.54,
visibility: 6.15
},
{
time: 1364392800,
summary: "Partly Cloudy",
icon: "partly-cloudy-day",
precipIntensity: 0,
temperature: 29.26,
windSpeed: 2.95,
windBearing: 45,
cloudCover: 0.36,
humidity: 0.88,
pressure: 832.05,
visibility: 6.14
}..................}
```

I would like to loop through the data array.

I get the Hourly data by doing this:

```
String hourly = json.getString("hourly");
```

However, I am not getting the data array from within the hourly string. What am I missing?

Am I on the right path here:

```
   JSONObject h = json.getJSONObject("hourly");
    String d = json.getString("data");

JSONArray a = h.getJSONArray("data");

                for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
                    // Pulling items from the array
                    String s = h.getString("summary");
                    String t = h.getString("temperature");
                    aq.id(R.id.tv).text("Summary: " + s + "Temp: " + t);
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Hourly` is a JSONObject and inside it a `JSONArray` named data by using org.json API you can easily loop throw them using the following code:

```
   JSONObject hourly = new JSONObject(json.getString("hourly"));
   JSONArray array = hourly.getJSONArray("data");
   for (int i=0; i< array.length(); i++){
       JSONObject obj = data.getJSONObject(i);
         //do whatever you want with your data 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the obj within my array initally. This helped!

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `JSONArray`, as you've mentioned it yourself, that data is an `array` in your `JSONObject`.

```
JSONArray dataArray = hourlyObj.getJSONArray("data");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSONArray` to get the `data` value and `JSONObject` to get `hourly`.

**Hourly Object**

```
JSONObject hourlyObj = json.getJSONObject("hourly");
```

**Data Array**

```
JSONArray yourdataArray = hourlyObj.getJSONArray("data"); 
// loop it
 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){  
         JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         String time = json_data.getString("time");
         // and so on 
     }
```

You will get all the values in data.

Comment: Great answer. Well laid out :) Thanks for adding to my question.

Comment: Glad to help you.If my answer helped you. then upvote and mark as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample snippet that would help you.

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(results);
                JSONArray albums = jObj.getJSONArray("pickups");

                for (int i = 0; i < albums.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = albums.getJSONObject(i);
                    String  id = c.getString("id");

                    Record objRecord=new Record();
                    objRecord.setId(c.getString("id"));
                    objRecord.setName(c.getString("name"));
                    objRecord.setNumber(c.getString("number"));
                    objRecord.setTime(c.getString("time"));

                    PickupList.arrayList.add(objRecord);

                }
```